# Fourier transform of $e^{it\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is clear, I came up with this Fourier transform to calculate while searching explicit solutions for a PDE, but I don't even know if it is feasible.

$
\mathcal{F}_x(e^{it\sqrt{a^2+x^2}})
$

with $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ if possible. I would really appreciate some help, or references for this kind of transforms.